# Buying iphone connected to a carrier for wifi

Tags: iphone, wifi, ipod-touch, cellular-carriers

As of right now I don't have a smartphone, but am debating getting one in the near future (although not sure in how long that will be.) My old itouch just broke, so i wanted to know if it is possible to buy an iphone off ebay, one that is connected to verizon (not unlocked) and use it with just wifi until I decide to add it to my network?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure the iPhone is not blacklisted.

You can use Verizon site:

http://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/nso/enterDeviceId.do

Depending on the iPhone model (`CDMA` or `GSM`) you need to enter `MEID` or `IMEI` code.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, absolutely. You can buy and use an iPhone without a sim card installed at all and just use it on wifi. However if you want to get a plan later you will need to go with verizon or find a way to unlock it, if that's at all possible.

Comment: Verizon uses also `CDMA` network, a CDMA phone has no sim slot.